# What is the Taylor Expansion of a function

Tags: taylor-expansion

What is the Taylor expansion of the function 
$$G(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^{50})(1-x^{25})(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x)}\quad ?$$

Comment: Do you mean $\dfrac{1}{(1-x^{50})(1-x^{25})(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x)}$?

Comment: yes, I do. Sorry, not too good at formatting ;)

Comment: What did you try? The function seems to be  related to a change-counting problem.

Comment: It's $\sum a_nx^n$ where $a_n$ is the number of solutions of $n=c_1+5c_5+10c_{10}+25c_{25}+50c_{50}$ in non-negative integers.

Comment: Yes it is, I'm trying to find an efficient way to calculate how many combinations of {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200} cents to make 200 cents

Comment: There is a formula at https://oeis.org/A001300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum{x^n}$ , $n\ge0$ $$G(x)=(\sum{x^n})(\sum{x^{5n}})(\sum{x^{10n}})(\sum{x^{25n}})(\sum{x^{50n}})$$

Comment: ... which leads back to Robert Z's change-counting problem.